# Handle onSubmit in react child components

Tags: reactjs, forms

What is the most elegant and react-like way of handling an onSubmit event on child componenets.
Currently I have a parent form component containing all the corresponding fields. When I click submit the parent component handles everything and sens a POST request to the server with the data.
The problem now is, the form needs to do more stuff, showing fields for a referenced resource, and creating those references on the server, similar to the parent component.
Separating this to multiple submit buttons is no problem, but I want ONE submit button, and I want the onSubmit handling logic separated in child components. So when I click on submit, the parent creates the main resource on the server, and the child components create their stuff.
How can this be accomplished in react in an elegant way, as react is more suited for passing data from parent to child. How can the children also react on the onSubmit event together with the parent component?

Comment: Pass the parent function as a prop on the child and simply call it within the child: ```props.handleMyParentFunction();```

Comment: It seems like a way to do it, but I have multiple child components, so which one should be responsible for this? It just doesn't feel like the right way to do this.

Comment: this is a standard react way of doing things, multiple child components should not pose a problem

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much as easy as this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Contact from "./contact";
import classes from "./Component.css";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {}

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("submitted");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Contact submit={this.onSubmit} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React from "react";

const Contact = (props) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className={classes.Container}>
      <button onSubmit={props.submit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);

export default Contact;
```

If this doesn't work you could save the function to context or redux dependant on your use case.

Feel free to send me your code and i will see what i can do :)

Comment: Yes but then all the logic needs to remain in the parent component, but I want to separate the logic

Comment: Ah i'm with you then you will want to use React hooks if you want a component to use it's own state.